# Recaptcha Gem Isn't Preventing Submit When Unchecked (Rails 5.2)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have what should be a very basic setup with the [Recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) gem.  It is showing all the appropriate on-page behavior:  A recaptcha "I am not a robot" box appears on the sign up screen and is checkable by the user.

However, if I try and submit the sign in form without checking the box, it still goes through instead of showing an error message.

I followed the Gem's instructions pretty much verbatim:

- I created the appropriate keys on Google's website and put them into
  Heroku's variable storage successfully.
- I put `gem 'recaptcha'` in my Gemfile and bundled.
- I added `<%= recaptcha_tags %>` in my sign up form (Devise new user
  registration).
- I changed my create method to include `if verify_recaptcha(model:
  @user) && @user.persisted?` in my registrations controller.

The box is showing up perfectly, but the user is able to create a new account even without checking the recaptcha box!

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here?  You can see the issue live [here](https://www.thestaysanemom.com/users/sign_up) if you need to Google inspector it...

Comment: Just do a cross check whether you have obtained a right key and using right method against that.You should use respective methods based on your key type. Check https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha#obtaining-a-key

Comment: have you `prepend_before_action` to verify `ReCaptcha` in you're `RegistrationsController` ?